# Ajax security of Facebook apps? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, facebook, security

I have a simple voting app where I would like the vote event to be done via ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/vote',
  data: '',
})
```

However, the signed_request is not passed by FB as a parameter for ajax calls. What is the best practice for verifying identity of an ajax request for Facebook apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the signed_request is not passed by FB as a parameter for ajax calls.

It’s **You** (your script) making these HTTP requests, a.k.a. ajax calls. Why (w|s)hould Facebook add anything to those?

> What is the best practice for verifying identity of an ajax request for Facebook apps?

If all you do is AJAX requests, I think it’s a good idea to pass the signed_request parameter for server-side validation – so why don’t you just do it …?

Comment: Well, I am looking for best practices in this regard.